# Incorrect proof of Morrey's conjecture

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Morrey conjectured that Rank 1 convexity does not imply quasiconvexity and this was shown to be true for $n \geq 3$ by V.Sverak.

Are there any proofs (rather failed attempts) which went about trying to show Rank-1 convex functions are quasiconvex?

I am specifically looking for references where incorrect proofs were proposed.

Comment: Dacorogna's Direct Method in the Calculus of Variations book might have some reference.

Comment: I did look through Dacorogna's book, but most of the references therein are towards positive resolution of Morrey's conjecture. I am specifically looking for techniques that might have led to an incorrect proof of the implication that rank 1 convex implies quasiconvex.